# I want to see only domain name and if enter anything in url I want to see that word in url and it has to redirect to another page using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**[www.somesite.com/dog](http://www.somesite.com/dog)**
If I enter something after url I have to see that only not any controller name or view name

Comment: Well yes you shouldn't see view names ever and you won't see controller names unless you're using the default routing. You can set up routing rules to do whatever you need. I'm not sure about the question in your title, though - can you explain what the redirect would be? To a different page on the same site? Without changing the URL?

Comment: how is the configuration done. this is one of those questions that really needs some additional details.

Comment: @Rup if u enter anything in the url after domain like(www.somesite.com/someword) then, I take that value using javascript and validate it  and redirect to another page according to the validation.after redirecting it I don't want to see the redirected view name or its controller name in the url(www.somesite/site/controllername(I don't want to see)/viewname(don't want to see))..just show me how setup routing...even after all this if u won't get my point...www.protectedtext.com see this site's url pattern

Comment: Why are you doing the validation with JavaScript not in C#? If you did then want to redirect then you'll have to change the URL. Why not just do the validation and page selection on the server? That said if you did want to do this with JavaScript then rather than redirecting you could also load the page content over AJAX, which you would do without changing the URL.

Comment: @Rup as u suggested I will go with ajax can please help me out with this issue...by giving me few example..